# Chrome Android keydown event.preventDefault() not working

Tags: javascript, android, preventdefault

The following code does not work on android devices:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <input type="text" id="test" />
</body>
</html>

document.getElementById("test").addEventListener("keydown", e => {
  e.preventDefault();
})
```

You can test it: https://output.jsbin.com/neluhohadi
Link to jsbin: https://jsbin.com/neluhohadi/edit?html,js

This works as expected on iOS devices.